# центрирование div относительно друг друга

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Два блока div с border в css. Должны быть рядом относительно друг друга на одинаковой высоте.
Как сделать?
И как сделать отступ между строками больше(в теге "a")?
Простите, я совсем-совсем начинающий
Приложил скрин и код.
[image: скрин]

```css
.header {
  font-family: "Consolas", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}
body{
  background-color: gray;
}
.one{
  border: 7px solid rgba(255, 145, 0, 0.8);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
}

.one p {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

.two {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 7px solid rgba(255, 145, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Link</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="header">
        <h1><strong>Полезные ссылки для программистов</strong></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="one">
        <p>Html</p>
        <a href="//proglang.su/html-reference/tags">ProgLang - Все теги языка HTML(с&nbsp;описанием)</a>
        <br>
        <a href="//htmlreference.io">HTMLReference.io - Все теги языка HTML&nbsp;#2</a>
        <br>
        <a href="//validator.w3.org">W3School - Валидатор кода</a>
    </div>

    <div class="two">
        <p>Css</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение - создать обёртку для двух дивов. Плюс немного оптимизировать css

```css
.header {
  font-family: "Consolas", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}
body{
  background-color: gray;
}
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.one, .two {
  border: 7px solid rgba(255, 145, 0, 0.8);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
}

.one p, .two p {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="header">
      <h1><strong>Полезные ссылки для программистов</strong></h1>
  </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="div one">
            <p>Html</p>
                <a href="//proglang.su/html-reference/tags">ProgLang - Все теги языка HTML(с&nbsp;описанием)</a>
                <br>
                <a href="//htmlreference.io">HTMLReference.io - Все теги языка HTML&nbsp;#2</a>
                <br>
                <a href="//validator.w3.org">W3School - Валидатор кода</a>
        </div>

        <div class="div two">
            <p>Css</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ

```css
.header {
  font-family: "Consolas", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  padding-top: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}
body{
  background-color: gray;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
}

li{
  padding: 6px;
}

.one{
border: 7px solid rgba(255, 145, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;

}


.one p {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

.two {
  border: 7px solid rgba(255, 145, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
    
    <div class="header">
        <h1><strong>Полезные ссылки для программистов</strong></h1>
    </div>

  <div class="flex">
        <div class="one">
        <p>Html</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="//proglang.su/html-reference/tags">PROGLANG - ВСЕ ТЕГИ ЯЗЫКА</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="//htmlreference.io">HTML(С ОПИСАНИЕМ)</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="//validator.w3.org">W3School - Валидатор кода</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="two">
        <p>Css</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```